# Does a thread start immediately

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I just started reading C++ Concurrency In Action 2012. In Chapter 2, it shows a thread being invoked and joined. With the join not being an atomic operation with thread creation. By this I mean that the thread is started with `std:thread t(...)` and in a succeeding line a `join` is performed. My assumption is that when a thread is created it can begin executing at any time, including at once. And if it begins executing at once and terminates before the creating program begins executing, then the `join` fails.

The same issue occurs when if `t.joinable()` is used.

If my guess is correct then there is no guarantee that a `join` can ever be successful and the `joinable()`predicate does not help. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe that `join()` will succeed even if the thread has already ended. It wouldn't be much use otherwise. See [joinable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) for more details.

Comment: Can a thread be created in a suspended state, joined, and then caused to execute or is this something that has to be done programmatically?

Comment: Yes, c++ has no notion of a suspended thread, so you would have to do it programatically. Some use of [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) would probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join method essentially says "block execution until the thread completes at which time return from my call to join".

If a thread has already run and exited by the time you call join it will simply immediately return. If the thread is still running then your call to join will be blocked until the thread completes at which point it will return. In neither of these situations will there be a failure.

The following is the exact text of the documentation for the join function:

> The function returns when the thread execution has completed.
>
> This synchronizes the moment this function returns with the completion
>   of all the operations in the thread: This blocks the execution of the
>   thread that calls this function until the function called on
>   construction returns (if it hasn't yet).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/

Comment: Wow. Listing 2.7 of the book has multiple thread creation followed by multiple joins. This seems to be really deceptive code in that the longest executing program dictates the join behaviors and the 'what to do next'. Is there anyway to start a program in a suspended state and to do something other than a 'join' to gain control over the created thread? Is this something that a thread pool solves (I haven't gotten to them yet).

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez First off if this answers your initial question you should accept it.

The reason you see a lot of code where it executes a bunch of threads then joins them all is simple. It is basically saying "make all these threads execute in parallel and run until their tasks are done. Wait until ALL my threads have completed at which point continue onward with my program (or exit)"

You should probably start a new question though if you want more detail. I have limited space to answer in the comments. But I can say join isnt about "control" its just to wait till a thread exists.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez Also this for the other part of your comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524775/delayed-start-of-a-thread-in-c-11

Answer (score 1):

A `thread` object may represent a thread of execution, but that does not mean the actual thread of execution is running (even if it was at some point in time).

In other words, when you construct a `thread` object (that represents an actual thread of execution, i.e. you use the non-default constructor) and its associated thread of execution ends, this event does **not** change the state of the `thread` object. It will still be `joinable()`.

More precisely, according to [[thread.thread.class]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/thread.thread.class), the post-condition of the non-default constructor is `get_id() != id()` (i.e. the object represents an actual thread of execution). The only way to change that condition is either `join()` or `detach()` (or moving it) -- the fact that the thread of execution has finished or not does not change the return value of `get_id()`. This note of the standard clarifies the only events that can change the condition:

> [ Note: A thread object does not represent a thread of execution after default construction, after being moved from, or after a successful call to detach or join.  — end note ]