# C++ std::thread terminate called without an active exception Aborted

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, oop, c++17

I have a code here that captures the video stream from a camera running the video capture operation in a separate thread. The code compiles but when I try to run it I am receiving the following error.

I did some research and found out that this problem is related to the absence of `th.join();` but I already do this when the user interrupts the process by pressing the `q` key. Until then, the code should keep on running in the created thread. So this tells me that I should join the thread somewhere else.

If I remove the thread by replacing `thread th(&VideoCaptureAsync::update, this);` with `VideoCaptureAsync::update();` and deleting `th.join();`, the error goes away but this obviously defeats the purpose of this code.

**Output**

> Inside initiate function
>
> (process:10748): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state:
>   assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
>
> Inside start function
>
> Inside update function
>
> terminate called without an active exception
>
> Inside read function
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

**Code**

```
/*
* Asynchronous_video_capture.cpp
*
* Copyright (C) 2019 C. S. G.
*
* MIT License
*/

#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>     // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat)
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>  // Video write
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void foo(bool &keep_run){
    cout << "Inside the thread: Interrupt flag = " << keep_run << endl;
    if (std::cin.get() == 'q') {
        keep_run = false;
        cout << "User Interrupted the process. Interrupt flag = " << keep_run << endl;
    }
}

class VideoCaptureAsync
{
private:
    VideoCapture cam;
    thread th;
    bool read_lock;
    Mat frame;
    Mat grabbed;
    bool isStarted;
public:
    void initiate(unsigned int camId, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, double fps);
    void start();       // a start function to create and start the thread
    void update();      // an update function that will be called asynchronously
    tuple<Mat, Mat> read();        // a read function that we will call from our code to retrieve a new frame.
    void stop();        // a stop function to stop (join) the thread
    void exit();        // an __exit__ function to clean up some resources.
};

void VideoCaptureAsync::initiate(unsigned int camId, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, double fps){
    cout << "Inside initiate function" << endl;
    cam.open(camId);
    if (!cam.isOpened())
    {
        cerr  << "Could not open the VideoCapture camera: " << camId << endl;
    }
    cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);
    cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);
    cam.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, fps);

    isStarted = false;
    read_lock = false;
    VideoCaptureAsync::start();
}

void VideoCaptureAsync::start(){
    cout << "Inside start function" << endl;
    if (isStarted) {
        cout << "Asynchroneous video capturing has already been started" << endl;
    }
    isStarted = true; 
    thread th(&VideoCaptureAsync::update, this);
    //VideoCaptureAsync::update();
}

void VideoCaptureAsync::update(){
    cout << "Inside update function" << endl;
    while(isStarted){
        Mat frame_update;
        Mat grabbed_update;
        tie(frame_update, grabbed_update) = VideoCaptureAsync::read();
        if(!read_lock){
            frame_update.copyTo(frame);
            grabbed_update.copyTo(grabbed);
        }
    }
}

tuple<Mat, Mat> VideoCaptureAsync::read(){
    cout << "Inside read function" << endl;
    if (!read_lock){
        read_lock = true;
        Mat frame_read;
        cam.read(frame_read);
        Mat grabbed_read;
        read_lock = false;
        return make_tuple(frame_read, grabbed_read);
    }
}

void VideoCaptureAsync::stop(){
    cout << "Inside stop function" << endl;
    th.join();
    isStarted = false;
    read_lock = true;
}

void VideoCaptureAsync::exit(){
    cout << "Finished writing ..." << endl;
    cam.release();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    const unsigned int camId = 1;
    const bool enableOutput = true;
    const unsigned int w = 1280;
    const unsigned int h = 720;
    double fps = 30.0;


    VideoCaptureAsync obj;
    obj.initiate(camId,w,h,fps);
    bool keep_running = true;
    thread th1(foo, std::ref(keep_running));
    Mat original_frame;

    while (keep_running) {
        std::tie(std::ignore, original_frame) = obj.read();

        if (enableOutput) {
            imshow("Retrieved Image", original_frame);
            waitKey(1000/fps);
        }
    }

    obj.stop();
    obj.exit();

}
```

Comment: "the absence of th.join(); but I already do this when the user interrupts the process by pressing the q key." -- which part of the above code relating to the `q` key processing executes `join()` on the running thread, as you claim? The shown code does no such thing.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It does. Pressing q breaks out of the while loop inside main() and then VideoCaptureAsync::stop() is executed which has the th.join() in it.

Comment: What does the `th` member of that class have anything to do with `th1` object in `main()`, the actual executing thread? `th.join()` does absolutely nothing to the `th1` object, which is the one that you need to actually stop. There does not appear to be any execution thread started by `th`, so calling its `join()` doesn't join anything from the looks of it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok, I've stopped `th1` too right before `obj.stop()` and that didn't solve the problem. I know for sure that the problem is to do with `th`, not `th1`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `start`() method:

```
thread th(&VideoCaptureAsync::update, this);
```

This statement creates a new local object in the `start()` method called `th`, a brand new, fresh off the assembly line, `std::thread` object, and constructs it in a manner that creates a new execution thread.

Immediately afterwards, `start()` returns. This destroys this local object, invoking its destructor, and resulting in your exception.

Your obvious intent is to use the `th` class member in order to create a new execution thread, instead of creating a new local object in the `start()` method. But the above C++ syntax is a declaration. It declares a new object, and when used in side a function it creates a new local object (in automatic scope), that gets automatically destroyed at the end of the scope. That's how C++ works.

In order to have the new execution thread started from your existing class member:

```
th=thread{&VideoCaptureAsync::update, this};
```

(using modern C++'s uniform initialization syntax). For more information see "[Delayed start of thread in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524775/delayed-start-of-a-thread-in-c-11)".