# Threading concepts c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
int main(){
std::thread t1(findEven, start, end, &(EvenSum));
    std::thread t2(findOdd, start, end, &(OddSum));
 
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Assume that findEven and findOdd are some functions that has already been written .
For better understandig , this is the code [Link to Code](https://ideone.com/ypngpe)

Having some difficulty in understanding threading concepts and wanted to check if my understanding is correct?
My main thread created a new thread T1  and ran the function Evensum .It did not wait for evensum to finish and came back and again launched a new thread T2 and running findodd at same time .now both t1 and t2 are running at the same time .that's fine.
now it hits t1.join () . Does it mean that the line t2.join() is not reached as long as t1 is not finished?

Comment: Yes. You understanding is correct. t2,join will hit only when t1 completes its job.

Comment: hey but why is it so ? I mean what's the logic for doing so ?I want to understand the philosophy behind this.

Comment: That's how `join` works.  It doesn't allow the thread that calls `join` to go on until the thread `join` was called on finishes executing.

Comment: If you don't want that, look into using `std::async` and it's returned `std::future` object.

Comment: t1.join() waits until t1 has finished, if t2 finished earlier then t2.join() will just "fall through", if t2 hasnt finished then t2.join() will wait.

Comment: I also prefer using std::async, the returned future even allows you to get a return value (or exception) back from the aysnchronous call.

Comment: The whole point of `join` is to "wait until the thread has finished executing, then continue". There are other tools available to synchronize threads in different ways. Not sure if there is any philosophy to it, more then the fact that it is very useful to be able to wait until a centain thread is finished sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is totally correct.

1. Thread invocation just triggers the thing and let it go independently (unless you provide extra options like "pending start" so you would activate created thread later upon demand).
2. Once asked to join, current (main?) thread is suspended until associated thread is signaled as completed. In case of multiple threads, you may wait for all, or for any of if necessary.

Comment: note: `std::thread` doesn't have an explicit "pending start" option. But you can easily achieve that with the default constructor + move thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524775/delayed-start-of-a-thread-in-c-11/25525465